# Attach csv file to django request

Tags: python, salesforce, httplib

I would like to add batch with csv file to a job in salesforce.com, according to [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_quickstart_add_batch.htm). I use the following code to do that, but it does not work (no new objects appear in salesforce):

```
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8',
        'X-SFDC-Session': client.sessionId
    }
    (_, host, path, _, _, _) = urlparse("https://%s/services/async/24.0/job/%s/batch" % (instance, job_id))
    csv_file = open('test.csv', "rb")
    t = csv_file.read()
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)
    conn.request("POST", path, t, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    rawResponse = response.read()
```

How can I attach file to request and send it?

Comment: You want to attach a file to the **request** as in attach a file to **conn.request** ?  Or do you want to attach a file to the **django response** ? I'm wondering if this is a question about httplib or django... the tags state "django" rather than "httplib"

Comment: @jpic: I want to send file to salesforce.com so I want to attach it to request not response. You are right about tags.

Answer (score 1):

The thing with the HTTP protocol, is that it requires some boilerplate to generate an HTTP request with attached binary contents.

Either use the [poster](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/) lib, either reuse a lower level [code snippet](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306-http-client-to-post-using-multipartform-data/) as there are [plenty](http://google.com/search?q=httplib+post+file).

Answer (score 1):

the records aren't processed until you update the job status to indicate you've uploaded all the batches in the job. see the [quickstart in the docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/asynch_api_quickstart_close_job.htm)